# Custom Post Type: Search Results - Template for no results

Tags: custom-post-types

My `custom-post-type` is a Property Listing and on the Homepage there is a Search form. The Search Form works fine if there is a Property or Properties Matching the results.

If there are no Properties matching their Search then for some reason it drops my `custom-post-type` page and it uses `index.php` to display a page.

The URL structure is like this:

```
localhost/wp-ps/properties/?area=&beds=&s-year=&s-status=&price-from=85&price-to=185
```

This will return all of the properties

```
localhost/wp-ps/properties/?area=&beds=&s-year=&s-status=student&price-from=85&price-to=185
```

This URL will return all Properties that have the taxonomy students between a price of 85 - 185.

Let say there are no properties found out all the URL will say be this

```
localhost/wp-ps/properties/?area=&beds=&s-year=&s-status=student&price-from=165&price-to=185
```

So here we're saying return results that are in the taxonomy student and have a price-from 165.

**The Problem:**
It will display whatever is in my `index.php` instead of using my property listing page like it would if there were results.

Answer (score 1):

If your search results page is defaulting to the `index.php` it's because you don't have a `search.php` template in your theme. Quite likely, your `index.php` template is also handling search results when items are found, too.

`search.php` template, if it exists should be used for search results whether or not any items were found. Just create one and put what you want to in it. See the bottom of the [template hierarchy diagram](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png)

Comment: Hmm.. I didn't think having a `search.php` would matter as the searchform is not coming from the `searchform.php` file

Comment: It shouldn't matter where the search was initiated if your concern is how to display the results. The search results are displayed using the `search.php` template if it exists, and if not, `index.php`.

Comment: Well that didn't seem to work - I added the `search.php` and added some random text within the file and when I searched for a property with say 10+ beds it still returns only the content inside the `index.php`

Comment: The only other thing I can think is that whatever mechanism is submitting the search isn't passing the search term properly to trigger a search query. To trigger the search query, the search form (whatever that is) should direct to your home url, using the get method, and the search term field has to have `name="s"` as an attribute.

Comment: It even doesn't have to redirect to home URL strictly. Any archive page and the `s` parameter should be enough to trigger search.

Comment: The thing is I'm not using the `s` parameter as the search form is a fully custom form - it has nothing to do with the WordPress search field as I have had to make the form match my custom post type results etc. Everything works fine when it finds a property but when it doesn't it just shows whatever is inside the `index.php` file